# breeding parents for multiple children in genetic algorithm

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

I'm building my first Genetic Algorithm in javascript, using a collection of tutorials.

I'm building a somewhat simpler structure to this scheduling tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/GaClassSchedule.aspx#Chromosome8, but I've run into a problem with breeding.

I get a population of 60 individuals, and now I'm picking the top two individuals to breed, and then selecting a few random other individuals to breed with the top two, am I not going to end up with a fairly small amount of parents rather quickly?

I figure I'm not going to be making much progress in the solution if I breed the top two results with each of the next 20.

Is that correct? Is there a generally accepted method for doing this?

Comment: Do you mean genetic instead of generic?

Comment: yes, genetic, not generic. sorry not much sleep the last few nights.

Comment: If I interpret your question correctly, you fear running out of individuals because you only pick a few parents from the population. Key is that your parents need to get just as many kids as required to keep the population size constant. So if you pick 5 parents from 60 individuals then each parent needs to get 11-12 kids so you end up with 60 new (or 55 new and 5 old) individuals in the next generation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a sample of genetic algorithms in Javascript [here](http://geneticoddity.appspot.com/).

One problem with your approach is that you are **killing diversity in the population** by mating always the top 2 individuals. That will never work very well because it's **too greedy**, and you'll actually be defeating the purpose of having a genetic algorithm in the first place.

This is how I am implementing mating with **elitism** (which means I am retaining a percentage of unaltered best fit individuals and randomly mating all the rest), and I'll let the code do the talking:

```
// save best guys as elite population and shove into temp array for the new generation
for(var e = 0; e < ELITE; e++) {
   tempGenerationHolder.push(fitnessScores[e].chromosome); 
}

// randomly select a mate (including elite) for all of the remaining ones
// using double-point crossover should suffice for this silly problem
// note: this should create INITIAL_POP_SIZE - ELITE new individualz
for(var s = 0; s < INITIAL_POP_SIZE - ELITE; s++) {
   // generate random number between 0 and INITIAL_POP_SIZE - ELITE - 1
   var randInd = Math.floor(Math.random()*(INITIAL_POP_SIZE - ELITE));

   // mate the individual at index s with indivudal at random index
   var child = mate(fitnessScores[s].chromosome, fitnessScores[randInd].chromosome);

   // push the result in the new generation holder
   tempGenerationHolder.push(child);
}
```

It is fairly well commented but if you need any further pointers just ask (and [here](https://github.com/JohnIdol/WasDarwinWrong)'s the github repo, or you can just do a view source on the url above). I used this approach (elitism) a number of times, and for basic scenarios it usually works well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks John, I've just been going through your code, on the 'was darwin wrong' and looking at the complete solution is making it much easier. You've done a great job of commenting it and making it clear. 

I can't say I've got my GA working right yet, but I think your help has me firmly on the right road.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

When I've implemented genetic algorithms in the past, what I've done is to pick the parents always probabilistically - that is, you don't necessarily pick the winners, but you will pick the winners with a probability depending on how much better they are than everyone else (based on the fitness function).

I cannot remember the name of the paper to back it up, but there is a mathematical proof that "ranking" selection converges faster than "proportional" selection. If you try looking around for "genetic algorithm selection strategy" you may find something about this.

EDIT:
Just to be more specific, since pedalpete asked, there are two kinds of selection algorithms: one based on rank, one based on fitness proportion. Consider a population with 6 solutions and the following fitness values:

```
Solution   Fitness Value
A          5
B          4
C          3
D          2
E          1
F          1
```

In ranking selection, you would take the top k (say, 2 or 4) and use those as the parents for your next generation. In proportional ranking, to form each "child", you randomly pick the parent with a probability based on fitness value:

```
Solution   Probability
A          5/16
B          4/16
C          3/16
D          2/16
E          1/16
F          1/16
```

In this scheme, F may end up being a parent in the next generation. With a larger population size (100 for example - may be larger or smaller depending on the search space), this will mean that the bottom solutions will end up being a parent some of the time. This is OK, because even "bad" solutions have some "good" aspects.

Comment: Thanks James, I'm not sure I understand the difference. If the best is the best, and the second best is the second best, what does it matter if the second is than the 3rd? Under what circumstances would you select the 3rd over the 2nd? or 5th for that matter?

Comment: @pedalpete Selection is perhaps the most crucial part of any selection algorithm. You can't just pick the top individuals - variance is needed, like in the real world. Imagine that the mutation of an otherwise bad individual could make it really good (or the crossing of two bad ones). Of course your choice has to be focused towards the better individuals, but you still have to have variance. Experiment with your parameters, they are problem specific.

Answer (score 3):

Keeping the absolute fittest individuals is called elitism, and it does tend to lead to faster convergence, which, depending on the fitness landscape of the problem, may or may not be what you want.  Faster convergence is good if it reduces the amount of effort taken to find an acceptable solution but it's bad if it means that you end up with a local optimum and ignore better solutions.

Picking the other parents completely at random isn't going to work very well.  You need some mechanism whereby fitter candidates are more likely to be selected than weaker ones.  There are several different selection strategies that you can use, each with different pros and cons.  Some of the main ones are described [here](http://watchmaker.uncommons.org/manual/ch03.html).  Typically you will use roulette wheel selection or tournament selection.

As for combining the elite individuals with every single one of the other parents, that is a recipe for destroying variation in the population (as well as eliminating the previously preserved best candidates).

If you employ elitism, keep the elite individuals unchanged (that's the point of elitism) and then mate pairs of the other parents (which may or may not include some or all of the elite individuals, depending on whether they were also picked out as parents by the selection strategy).  Each parent will only mate once unless it was picked out multiple times by the selection strategy.

Comment: elitism is not the problem here I think (it's actually almost always fine to use it for all practical purposes), the problem is that he's killing diversity by *always* mating one of the the top 2 individuals

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is likely to suffer from [premature convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_convergence). There are lots of other selection techniques to pick from though. One of the more popular that you may wish to consider is [Tournament selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_selection).

Different selection strategies provide varying levels of 'selection pressure'. Selection pressure is how strongly the strategy insists on choosing the *best* programs. If the absolute best programs are chosen every time, then your algorithm effectively becomes a [hill-climber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing); it will get trapped in local optimum with no way of navigating to other peaks in the fitness landscape. At the other end of the scale, no fitness pressure at all means the algorithm will blindly stumble around the fitness landscape at random. So, the challenge is to try to choose an operator with sufficient (but not excessive) selection pressure, for the problem you are tackling.

One of the advantages of the tournament selection operator is that by just modifying the size of the tournament, you can easily tweak the level of selection pressure. A larger tournament will give more pressure, a smaller tournament less.